# Is there an visual audit (for example alignment check) for PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When I'm done with a presentation I would like to check for common formating mistakes such as using to many font / sizes / colors. But also check the alignment of boxes, titles etc. is there a tool that can help me do this kind of "Audit"?

Comment: I wonder how the software would know what is appropriate. One person's style is anothers bad layout.

Comment: yeah it would need to be configurable / suggest edits

Answer (score 1):

Such a thing could probably be built as a custom-written add-in but there's nothing in PowerPoint itself that does this.